After choosing an item from a dropdown list on sheet1 then goto another sheet2 and choose matching item in another dropdown
After choosing an item from a dropdown list in cell B4 on sheet1 then goes to another sheet2 and then it auto selects matching item in another dropdown in cell B4. Is this possible?
For example drodown on Sheet1!B4

and if a certain date is selected then automatically goes to sheet2 and selects matching date in the dropdown cell B4 on sheet2.  This only needs to happen on 3 different dates on sheet1.
I already have the auto switch working to go to sheet2 if one of the 3 dates is selected in the dropdown on sheet1, but it doesn't go to the exact matching date in B4 dropdown on sheet2.  Here is the VBA code that switches from sheet1 to sheet2:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Range("B4").Value
        Case Is = "08/01/2024 - 08/18/2024"    
            Worksheets("Weeks3").Activate    
        Case Is = "09/30/2024 - 10/20/2024"    
            Worksheets("Weeks3").Activate            
        Case Is = "12/02/2024 - 12/22/2024"
            Worksheets("Weeks3").Activate
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Range("B4").Select
End Sub


Assuming your drop-down is a Data Validation list:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Only interested in changes to B4
    If Target.Address(False, False) <> "B4" Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Value
        'any of these values...
        Case "08/01/2024 - 08/18/2024", "09/30/2024 - 10/20/2024", "12/02/2024 - 12/22/2024"  
            'update the other sheet and activate it  
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weeks3")
                .Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value 'set same value
                .Activate
            End With    
    End Select
End Sub


This works quite well.  Thank you, Tim.  I tried to give you an upvote but my so called "reputation" is lacking so it was rejected.

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
